# Regex - remove 'a' tags where the link contains certain domains

Tags: php, regex

Say I have some text like so:

```
Lorem Ipsum <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6USO8krrmU">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6USO8krrmU</a> blah blah blah <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a> it's hot outside  <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6USO8krrmU" class="class1 class2">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6USO8krrmU</a>
```

..and I want to remove the link from around it if the href attribute contains youtube - for the sake of this example.

The output should be:

```
Lorem Ipsum http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6USO8krrmU blah blah blah <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a> it's hot outside  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6USO8krrmU
```

How can I achieve this?

While I have your attention, if anyone has any links to a good place to start learning regex I'd love to hear it.

Comment: obligatory reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: Tony the Pony, he c̼̪̞͔̯o͕m͖̬̠̤e͜ś̞̮̬͙͕̞!

Comment: A good regex tut is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: Don't use regex for that. Either do it right right away, or find an HTML parser (browsers normally have one, if you need to)

Comment: Just for further explanation: Because of the tree-nested and occasionally-exceptional formats accepted by HTML, it's likely someone could find a simple way around whatever Regex you write. Heck, if custom HTML is allowed, they could include a script tag.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: @STTLCU: Please don't post links to that question, because they are not helpful to the reader, unless you follow it up with something that is an answer they can use.  *You* know the point of the comment and that wall of text is that parsing HTML with regexes is a bad idea.  However, to someone else who is asking, that is not at all clear.  Worse, it doesn't point the reader to any useful solutions that *can* help parse HTML reliably.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href').lastIndexOf('youtube') >= 0;
}).contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 3):

I got there in the end with:

```
$string = preg_replace('#<a href="https?://www.youtube.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $string);
```