# replace link from domain and all possible subdomains, regex php

Tags: php, regex

I'm cleaning an `html` output that contains links to domain and /or subdomains what I reached is to clean all links from main domain with:

```
$content = preg_replace('#<a href="https?://domain.*?>.*?</a>#i', '', $content);
```

as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130476/regex-remove-a-tags-where-the-link-contains-certain-domains) , but, is it possible to create a regex to replace all links from a domain and all its subdomains?

something like:

```
preg_replace('#<a href="https?://**anysubdomain**.domain.*?>.*?</a>#i', '', $content);
```

Comment: Is this a help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378479/regular-expression-to-get-the-main-domain-of-a-url Look at the best answer ... (And also the comments, it should help you!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('#<a href="https?://(?:.+\.)?domain.*?>.*?</a>#i', '', $content);
```

The above should catch:

```
<a href="https://domain.com">something</a>
<a href="http://domain.net">...</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.org">...</a>
<a href="http://m.domain.com">...</a>
```

Comment: if the problem is with captures - you should replace it with `(?:.+\.)?`

Comment: replace what? you mean use (?:.+\.)? instead of "" ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `'#<a href="https?://(?:.+\.)?domain.*?>.*?</a>#i'` instead of `'#<a href="https?://(.+\.)?domain.*?>.*?</a>#i'`

Comment: I must make more tests, it stills messing but don't know why :(